# Preety url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have url `localhost/product/q.php?id=1&product=my-product`

how to make the url into `localhost/product/1/my-product` using .htaccess

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess file in your question.

Comment: im using this .httaccess code but not work

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/?$ product/q.php?id=$1$product=$2 [L]

Answer (score 1):

You use a `RewriteRule` which consists of a regex to apply to the *pretty URL* accessed by the user and a replacement which will then be used **by** the server/scripts.

```
RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)/(.*)$ /product/q.php?id=$1&product=$2 [L]
RewriteRule                                                           : Type of action
            ^product/(\d+)/(.*)$                                      : Regex to run against URL
                                 /product/q.php?id=$1&product=$2      : Replacement URL
                                                                 [L]  : Flags; L == Last
```

**Note**

Having re-read the question you may need to add:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

To the top of your `.htaccess` file  as well.

Comment: get it but css not include when I access the pretty url

Comment: What do you mean with `css`??

Comment: @DioMaulana or do you literally mean the stylesheet isn't working? In that case I need to see that link

Comment: when I access the pretty url, my site look like : https://prnt.sc/w8hzs2

but when i access with the localhost/product/q.php?id=1&product=my-product 
its clean

Comment: @DioMaulana then you  need to show the code for the page

Comment: problem solved sir, css prblem cause I didnt call it with base url

thankyou for helping me