# How to make seo url with htaccess on localhost?

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

i have liste.php file,
I call the php file like this

```
127.0.0.1/test/liste.php?id=yeni
```

liste.php file is located at site.com/test folder.

How can I make this SEO friendly as follows?

```
127.0.0.1/test/liste/yeni
```

I'm running the site localhost via xampp.

thank you

Comment: There are tons of duplicates of this question

Comment: I tried at least 50 tries but it didn't work

Comment: many are out of date or incorrect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preety url with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424077/preety-url-with-htaccess)

Comment: Post your closest attempt and what didn’t work

Comment: Simply put, even that doesn't work. I get an error not found. `RewriteRule ^home/ index.php [NC,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

**SORRY** I forgot the /test in the target :-(  (it is no good idea to answer regex questions while watching TV)

Put the following into your httpd.conf

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/test/(\w*)/(\w*)/?$  /test/$1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

This will do the following: http://test/liste/yeni/

It will take  the text between /test/   and the next slash /  in this case **liste** and use it as the name of the php file

and take the text after the slash (with or without trailing slash) in this cas **yeni** as id

If it should only rewrite to /test/liste.php?id=xyz  so oly the id is variable and not the name of the php file, then it would be even easier.

**AND DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART APACHE after changing the httpd.conf**

IF this DOES NOT WORK
then switch on tracing add the line
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3 before your rewrite rule.

So you have now the following lines at the end of your httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On 
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
RewriteRule ^/test/(\w*)/(\w*)/?$  /test/$1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

**RESTART APACHE!**

and go with your browser to to http://test/liste/yeni/

Now look into the error log located e.g. at C:\xampp\apache\logs

Now you can see all single steps of the mod_rewrite from your original clean URL to the "real url"   and can see if it works or at wich stage failure happens.

```
[Tue Jan 05 22:58:37.283228 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6724:tid 1828] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:54029] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2a4d7e8a298][rid#2a4d8998330/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/liste/yeni/

[Tue Jan 05 22:58:37.284227 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6724:tid 1828] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:54029] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2a4d7e8a298][rid#2a4d8998330/initial] applying pattern '^/test/(\\w*)/(\\w*)/?$' to uri '/test/liste/yeni/'

[Tue Jan 05 22:58:37.284227 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6724:tid 1828] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:54029] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2a4d7e8a298][rid#2a4d8998330/initial] rewrite '/test/liste/yeni/' -> '/test/liste.php?id=yeni'

[Tue Jan 05 22:58:37.284227 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6724:tid 1828] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:54029] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2a4d7e8a298][rid#2a4d8998330/initial] split uri=/test/liste.php?id=yeni -> uri=/test/liste.php, args=id=yeni

[Tue Jan 05 22:58:37.284227 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6724:tid 1828] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:54029] 127.0.0.1 - -[127.0.0.1/sid#2a4d7e8a298][rid#2a4d8998330/initial] local path result: /test/liste.php

[Tue Jan 05 22:58:37.284227 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6724:tid 1828] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:54029] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2a4d7e8a298][rid#2a4d8998330/initial] prefixed with document_root to C:/xampp/htdocs/test/liste.php

[Tue Jan 05 22:58:37.284227 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 6724:tid 1828] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:54029] 127.0.0.1 - -    [127.0.0.1/sid#2a4d7e8a298][rid#2a4d8998330/initial] go-ahead with C:/xampp/htdocs/test/liste.php [OK]
```

**IT worked :-) Voilá**

In access.log you will get only one line but with the correct code  200 :-)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:22:58:37 +0100] "GET /test/liste/yeni/ HTTP/1.1" 200 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
```

**If its working again remove the tracing line or put a # on the beginning of the line to mark it as comment**

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Try your regexps here and learn interactively:  (you have to escape the / with a backslash )
https://regex101.com/

Comment: this is not working i get 404 not found error

Comment: Remove leading slash from pattern if it is used in .htaccess

Comment: such as? `RewriteRule ^test(\w*)/(\w*)$  $1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
`

Comment: I'm about to go crazy :) i get 404 not found error

Comment: DID you restart APACHE?!?

Comment: I added some details and the debugging info.  if it still shoul not work. pats the error log -- as mine above in your original question.

Comment: thank you problem solved :)  you are great !