# how to add pagination in htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

I'm looking to add pagination with `htaccess`.

Visible URL:

```
example.com/test/page2
```

To:

```
example.com/test/pagination.php?page=2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preety url with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424077/preety-url-with-htaccess)

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried? Which of the thousands of examples online have you found that look similar to what you want? Hint: Apache doesn't care that the number is a page and not an ID, which is what you'll find more examples of.

Comment: @Steven Your edit seems to be an interpretation of the question, which is quite likely what was wanted, but not actually what they said. It would perhaps have been better to ask for clarification in a comment first.

Comment: I would recommend that you switch over to use the [front controller pattern](https://webdevetc.com/blog/the-front-controller-design-pattern-in-php) together with one of the many [routers](https://packagist.org/?query=router) out there instead. Then you define your routes in your code instead of in your htaccess file. That makes the flow much cleaner to read/follow and easier to set up, plus it will be easier to move your code between web servers since you don't need to configure a lot of vendor specific rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just need to capture the *page number* and then recycle it into the correctly formatted URL.

```
RewriteRule ^test/(\d+)/*$ /test/pagination.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule                                                  : Type of action
            ^test/(\d+)/*$                                   : Regex to run against URL
                           /test/pagination.php?page=$1      : Replacement URL
                                                        [L]  : Flags; L == Last
```

Example:

```
example.com/test/5     >>>     example.com/pagination?page=5
```